# Laravel 5 - How do you handle missing routes?

Tags: php, laravel

`App::missing` is not available and I can't find `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` It doesn't appear in my app directory:

[image: im]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/ebb7ebaf8cc4b353071df230957c99a4.png))</sub>

Am I using an old version of `laravel` or a not-complete source? Because everything works fine, but I want unknown routes to be redirected to some other route, such as a 404 page or a redirect to a homepage.

Comment: @watcher Please read the question, I don't have app/Exceptions/Handler.php in there

Comment: Have you looked at the readme in your files to see what version it is and then gone to the website and compared your version to the downloadable version?

Comment: It doesn't say the version in the readme file.

Comment: Looking at your directory structure, you have a Laravel 4 app there and not a Laravel 5 app.

Comment: Martin, you're right! @BenBeri L4 or L5?

Comment: Im guessing now I have laravel 5 then. please close this

Answer (score 5):

You could define a 'general' or 'capture all' route at the end of your routes.php that handle any requests that did not match any of your routes. Then display a view with a 'missing page' message.

```
Route::any('/', function()
{
    // your redirect code goes here
});
```

Comment: Down-voting. Not a good idea. A proper handler/view should be set up that’ll send the correct HTTP header (404).

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree. And this is what any developer should do in the 'your code here' place. I am leaving that to developer to decide what they need there. This is only a solution to capture and then handle request to routes that do not exist.

Comment: @MartinBean While I agree in principle, I would not downvote this because it is valid for some approaches, for example single page applications where you want to redirect to the home page without serving up a 404.